# Verify In-App Purchases with Firebase Realtime Database

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I'm trying to integrate in-app purchases into my app using Firebase Realtime database to verify/save records for the purchases. The problem is when I try to verify a purchase from client to back end server (Cloud functions) to check whether the key/purchaseToken already exist. But since Realtime Database can't store paths that contain "." (dot), how can I store and verify this information?

I think I can strip the dots from the strings but I don't know if that's the right way to do it.

Source: https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/security#verify

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a key that contains characters that are not allowed (such as a `.`), then I typically encoded that character either with something else (e.g. it is common to replace the `.` in an email address with a `,` in RTDB keys), or with a generic [URL encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding).